# How can i make this go code with multiple for loops faster?

Tags: performance, go, concurrency, physics

I recently started to work on this project . It's a model about collective motion.
In this code **8192 particle** move in **1000000 steps** and in each step each particles position and angle
updates. in each step neighbors of each particle sync their angle with that specific particle.
I wrote a code in python but that was so slow . then I wrote this code in go but it's still not fast . each step takes average 1.3 s which is not good .
do u guys have any idea about making it faster ?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

const (
    n_particles int     = 8192
    n_steps     int     = 1000000
    dt          float64 = 1.0
    v0          float64 = 0.5
    radius      float64 = 1.0
    f_intensity float64 = 1.2
    scale       float64 = 128.0

    alpha float64 = 1 / 36
)

var (
    x      [n_particles + 1]float64
    y      [n_particles + 1]float64
    angles [n_particles + 1]float64
    vx     [n_particles + 1]float64
    vy     [n_particles + 1]float64
    order  [n_steps + 1]float64
    fxk    float64
    fyk    float64
    fxi    float64
    fyi    float64
)

func main() {

    
    vstart := time.Now()
    rsource := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    randomizer := rand.New(rsource)
    //defining random data
    for i := 0; i <= n_particles; {
        x[i] = (randomizer.Float64()) * scale
        y[i] = (randomizer.Float64()) * scale
        angles[i] = (randomizer.Float64()) * math.Pi * 2
        vx[i] = v0 * float64(math.Cos(angles[i]))
        vy[i] = v0 * float64(math.Sin(angles[i]))

        i = i + 1

    }


    for i := 0; i <= n_steps; {

        start := time.Now()
        cosangles := 0.0
        sinangles := 0.0

        for j := 0; j <= n_particles; {

            x[j] = x[j] + (vx[j] * dt)
            x[j] = math.Mod(x[j], scale)
            y[j] = y[j] + (vy[j] * dt)
            y[j] = math.Mod(x[j], scale)

            j = j + 1
        }
        
        m_angles := angles

        for j := 0; j <= n_particles; {
            sumanglesx := 0.0
            sumanglesy := 0.0
            fxi = math.Floor(x[j])
            fyi = math.Floor(y[j])

            for k := 0; k <= n_particles; {
                if k != j {
                    fxk = math.Floor(x[k])
                    fyk = math.Floor(y[k])

                    if (fxi == fxk && fyi == fyk) || (fxi+1 == fxk && fyi == fyk) || (fxi-1 == fxk && fyi == fyk) || (fxi == fxk && fyi+1 == fyk) || (fxi == fxk && fyi-1 == fyk) || (fxi+1 == fxk && fyi+1 == fyk) || (fxi-1 == fxk && fyi-1 == fyk) || (fxi-1 == fxk && fyi+1 == fyk) || (fxi+1 == fxk && fyi-1 == fyk) {

                        dist := math.Pow((x[k]-x[j]), 2) + math.Pow((y[k]-y[j]), 2)
                        if dist < radius {
                            if k > j {
                                sx := math.Cos(angles[k])
                                sy := math.Sin(angles[k])
                                sumanglesx = sumanglesx + sx
                                sumanglesy = sumanglesy + sy

                            } else if k < j {
                                sx := alpha * math.Cos(angles[k])
                                sy := alpha * math.Sin(angles[k])
                                sumanglesx = sumanglesx + sx
                                sumanglesy = sumanglesy + sy

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

                k = k + 1

            }

            m_angles[j] = math.Atan2(sumanglesx, sumanglesy) + (f_intensity*randomizer.Float64() - f_intensity)

            j = j + 1
        }

        angles = m_angles
        for f := 0; f <= n_particles; {

            vx[f] = v0 * float64(math.Cos(angles[f]))
            vy[f] = v0 * float64(math.Sin(angles[f]))
            f = f + 1
        }

        for h := 0; h <= n_particles; {
            cosangles = cosangles + (math.Cos(angles[h]))
            sinangles = sinangles + (math.Sin(angles[h]))
            h = h + 1
        }

        core := (math.Sqrt(((math.Pow(cosangles, 2)) + (math.Pow(cosangles, 2))))) / float64(n_particles)
        order[i] = core
        duration := time.Since(start)
        fmt.Println(i)
        fmt.Println(duration)
        i = i + 1

    }
    vduration := time.Since(vstart)
    log.Printf("It took : %s", vduration)
    f, _ := os.Create("order.txt")
    for i := 0; i <= n_steps; {

        s := fmt.Sprintf("%f", order[i])

        w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
        w.WriteString(s + "\n")
        w.Flush()

        i = i + 1

    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you can extract code you are processing for each particle in different method and then using go-routines you can run it in parallel for multiple particles at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some minor quick wins:

- `math.Pow(x, 2)` => `x * x`
- `math.Sin`, `math.Cos` => [`math.Sincos`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Sincos)

But a bigger issue is looping over *n_particles*<sup>2</sup>, which is wasteful given that apparently only adjacent particles interact:

```
for j := 0; j <= n_particles; j++ {
    fxi = math.Floor(x[j])
    fyi = math.Floor(y[j])
    for k := 0; k <= n_particles; k++ {
        fxk = math.Floor(x[k])
        fyk = math.Floor(y[k])
        if (fxi == fxk && fyi == fyk) || (fxi+1 == fxk && fyi == fyk)
            || (fxi-1 == fxk && fyi == fyk) || (fxi == fxk && fyi+1 == fyk)
            || (fxi == fxk && fyi-1 == fyk) || (fxi+1 == fxk && fyi+1 == fyk)
            || (fxi-1 == fxk && fyi-1 == fyk) || (fxi-1 == fxk && fyi+1 == fyk)
            || (fxi+1 == fxk && fyi-1 == fyk) {
            // ...
```

How can you loop over adjacent particles without a *N*<sup>2</sup> nested loop? Perhaps if you maintain a helper adjacency index mapping integral x/y coordinates to particles, you can loop over it in a single pass?

```
for i := 0; i <= n_steps; i++ {
    // . . .
    type intpos struct {
        x, y int64
    }
    adjacencyIndex := make(map[intpos][]int)

    for j := 0; j <= n_particles; j++ {
        // . . .
        ix, iy := int64(math.Floor(x[j])), int64(math.Floor(y[j]))
        adjacencyIndex[intpos{ix, iy}] = append(adjacencyIndex[intpos{ix, iy}], j)
    }
    // . . .
    for j := 0; j <= n_particles; j++ {
        // . . .
        ix, iy := int64(math.Floor(x[j])), int64(math.Floor(y[j]))
        for dx := -1; dx <= 1; dx++ {
            for dy := -1; dy <= 1; dy++ {
                adjacentParticles := adjacencyIndex[intpos{ix + int64(dx), iy + int64(dy)}]
                for _, k := range adjacentParticles {
                    if j < k {
                        // process interaction between particles j and k
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // . . .
```

Note that the above will result in a single interaction between each pair of adjacent particles. If you need a bidirectional interaction (i.e. `j <=> k` *and* `k <=> j`), change `j < k` to `j != k`.

As a further improvement you can update the adjacency index as particles move around instead of rebuilding it in each iteration.

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your help  . I imagine boxes in system which they have id like (a,b) . a = floor(x) and b = floor(y) . But there is a radius which is a constant. I try to only check 8 boxes around my particle and box which my particle placed in . after getting particles in these boxes then i try to check them if they are in radius of my particle . by doing this i try to decrease checking particles from all the particles to the particles placed in those 9 boxes but also i check if they are in defined radius.